# Is it possibile to run multiple batch files that redirect their output to a single command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

This is a relatively 'How To' question than a bug. I would like to know how it would be possible to have multiple instances of a batch program redirect their output to a single window.

Is there any possible way of doing this?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuMm2.png]